# Add number between digits in range

Tags: python, loops, range

I have a range 10-20 and I want to add a 0 in between each digit, so for example:

range(10,15) returns 10, 11, 12, 13, 14

I want it to loop through and return 1000, 1010, 1020, 1030 and 1040.

I tried this:

```
a = range(10,20)

for i in a: 
    i.append(0)
    print (i)
```

No luck. Error message says:

```
    i.append(0)
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'append'
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Any reason why you don't want to use `range(1000, 1050, 10)`?

Comment: I was thinking about Android combinations, numbers 1-9, but you're right, in this case, that range would work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to add strings to a number which you can't. You should first convert the number to a string.

```
[int('0'.join(str(i))+'0') for i in range(10, 20)]
```

Answer (score 1):

As Tim Pietczker mentioned in his comment (which is much more an answer), you don't need to stuck with ranges of one increment. You can simply:

```
a = range(1000,2000,10)
```

However, your original code can be fixed like this:

```
a = range(10,20)

for i in a:
    si=str(i)   # convert your i integer to si string
    newsi=''    # initalize a new empty string
    for letter in si:      # loop through your string of digits
        newsi+=letter      # add the oncoming digit to the new string
        newsi+=0           # add a 0 to the new string
    newi=int(newsi)  # convert your new string to integer
    print newi
```

Comment: While this solution works, a more pythonic one-liner does the job.

Comment: +1 for showing how the OP's code can be cleaned: this is good for comprehension, before shifting to something faster/smarter/easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

This task can be solved either using strings (the 0's are being implicitly appended here) or by keeping this problem in the integer domain. Build either approach as a function and then use a list comprehension or built-in `map` to add 0's to every item in your range.

Option 1: convert to string, add 0's, convert back to integer

```
int(''.join((s+'0' for s in str(13)))
```

Option 2: stay in integer domain

```
result = 0
digit = 0
num = 14
while num>1:
    result += 10**(2*digit) * (num % 10)
    num //= 10 # integer division
    digit += 1
return result
```

By any chance were you looking for `range(1000, 1050, 10)`, which gives the values `1000, 1010, 1020, 1030, 1040`?